# Root.mainloop() then disregards the code below

Tags: python, tkinter

i am new to coding and i wanted to create a bot that could make computer life easier. I was trying to put a animation in using tkinter, but after i put the root.mainloop() after the tkinter code, it disregards the code below. Sample below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import datetime
class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
"""
A Label that displays images, and plays them if they are gifs
:im: A PIL Image instance or astring filename
"""

def load(self, im):
    if isinstance(im, str):
        im = Image.open(im)
    frames = []

    try:
        for i in count(1):
            frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
            im.seek(i)
    except EOFError:
        pass
    self.frames = cycle(frames)

    try:
        self.delay = im.info['duration']
    except:
        self.delay = 100

    if len(frames) == 1:
        self.config(image=next(self.frames))
    else:
        self.next_frame()

def unload(self):
    self.config(image=None)
    self.frames = None

def next_frame(self):
    if self.frames:
        self.config(image=next(self.frames))
        self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)

lbl = ImageLabel(root)
lbl.pack()
lbl.load('pyimage1.gif')
root.mainloop()

def WishMe():
hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
    speak("Good Morning !")             

elif hour <= 12 and hour < 18:
    speak("Good Afternoon !")

else:
    speak("Good Evening !")
```

Comment: Your code has too many issues (wrong indentation, undefined names; missing imports) to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the many issues with undefined names and missing imports, what you are doing is to *define* a function after the main loop. That in itself is ok.

But you are never actually *calling* this function.

And even if you did, you could only call it *after* it was defined (otherwise you would get a `NameError` exception). So `WishMe` could only run *after* the `mainloop` exits and the window was closed. It is unclear if this is what you intend.